# matplotlib multiple plots on one axis through loop does not update y_lim

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I need to create a figure which contains multiple Gaussian histograms from a list of parameters (pairs of mu and sigma). What I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

def single_camel_plot(mu, sigma, ax):
    x = np.linspace(mu - 4*sigma, mu + 4*sigma, 1000)
    sns.lineplot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma), ax=ax)
    ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mu_sigma_pairs = [(16900, 2100), (18200, 1500)]
for mu, sigma in mu_sigma_pairs:
    single_camel_plot(mu, sigma, ax)
```

The output is this figure.

[image: figure with wrong y_lim]

Ideally, the two histograms would use a single y-axis instead of a secondary axis, and the `ylim` should adjust to accomodate the tallest curve.

Comment: Seems to me that the `set_ylim(bottom=0)` is the culprit. After commented it out it no longer creates the problem. It's strange that somehow the other parameter `top` is also affected by `set_ylim` although I did not specify a value for it.

Comment: Setting the limit (even one) for your y-axis will turn off autoscaling. I don't think there's any way to autoscale only one end of the axis limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the limit outside the loop, such that it can autoscale when the plot is already filled.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

def single_camel_plot(mu, sigma, ax):
    x = np.linspace(mu - 4*sigma, mu + 4*sigma, 1000)
    ax.plot(x, stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma))   

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mu_sigma_pairs = [(16900, 2100), (18200, 1500)]
for mu, sigma in mu_sigma_pairs:
    single_camel_plot(mu, sigma, ax)

ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)   # <-------  HERE

plt.show()
```